# Why selenium and firefox webdriver cannot crawl wesite tags loaded by ajax

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

I want to get some HTML tags' texts from [bonbast](https://bonbast.com/) which some elements are loaded by ajax (for example tag with "ounce_top" id). I have tried selenium and geckodriver but again I can not crawl these tags and also when robotic firefox (geckodriver) opens, these elements are not shown on the web page! I have no idea why it happens. How can I crawl this website?

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_news = 'https://bonbast.com/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url_news)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
a = driver.find_element_by_id(id_="ounce_top")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally to extract the desired text i.e. ***1,817.43*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://bonbast.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.acceptcookies"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#ounce_top"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://bonbast.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.acceptcookies"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='ounce_top']"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1,817.43
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

Answer (score 1):

To do that with Selenium you will need to add a wait / delay. Preferably to use the expected conditions explicit wait.
I guess you are trying to get the text value inside that element?
This should work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url_news = 'https://bonbast.com/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url_news)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
your_gold_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ounce_top"))).text
```